# SQL*PLUS html report trimming large column

Tags: html, oracle, report, sqlplus

I am generating html report of my query results, from sqlplus,
I have few columns as clob datatype,

What I have observed that the html report is trimming large value in output.
Could someone please help?

Below is my command:

sqlplus -S -M "HTML ON TABLE 'BORDER="2"'" ***/**@//localhost:1521/locdb @sql/results.sql>results.html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8FRy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to add something like this to your script:

```
set long 2000000000
```

See [set long docs](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG088).